# How to set two variables to get the same value while generating data using faker in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, factory

I have a factory for generating the event

```
public function definition()
{
  return [
      'event_type' => $this->faker->randomElement(['class','event']),
      'event_name' => $this->faker->sentence(1,2),
      'date' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '+1 days', $endDate = '+5 days'),
      'start_time' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('+0 hours', '+2 hours'),
      'end_time' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('+3 hours', '+10 hours'),
  ];
}
```

Here I need `start_time` and `date` to have the same value generated in `date`

For example if `date='2003-03-15 02:00:49'`. I wanted the `start_time` to be `02:00:49` but I get some other value because it is generated randomly.

**Note: `date` is a timestamp and `start_time` is in time format in database**

Comment: why you don't store fake date into a variable and then use it?

Comment: Why do you say, you want `start_time` and `date` to be the same value but define `start_time` as `'+0 hours', '+2 hours'` and `date` as `$startDate = '+1 days', $endDate = '+5 days'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-use faker data by putting it into a variable first and get the timestamp of a `DateTime` object by calling its `getTimestamp()` method:

```
public function definition()
{
  $date = $this->faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '+1 days', $endDate = '+5 days');
  return [
      'event_type' => $this->faker->randomElement(['class','event']),
      'event_name' => $this->faker->sentence(1,2),
      'date' => $date->getTimestamp(),
      'start_time' => $date,
      'end_time' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('+3 hours', '+10 hours'),
  ];
}
```

Comment: How to add conditions to time stamp like i want the start_time to be after one hour from now.

Comment: You can change `$date = $this->faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '+1 days', $endDate = '+5 days');` to whatever you like.